# Django Rest Framework: How to set authentication in `urls.py`?

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I'm developing a REST API using the Django Rest Framework.

For authentication, I use,

- [django-rest-framework-simplejwt](https://github.com/SimpleJWT/django-rest-framework-simplejwt)
- [dj-rest-auth](https://github.com/jazzband/dj-rest-auth)

I now know how to set up auth for a specific view of an endpoint.
But I couldn't find a way of setting a URL pattern protected.

For example, I have two apps named `an_app` and `another_app`.
Here's my project's `urls.py` file.

```py
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('auth/', include('dj_rest_auth.urls')),
    path('auth/signup/', include('dj_rest_auth.registration.urls')),

    path('public_contents/', include('an_app.urls')),
    path('private_contents/', include('another_app.urls')),
]
```

The two URLs - `public_contents` and `private_contents` are both accessible without authenication.
I want to make the `public_contents` accessible by anybody, and want to make the `private_contents` accessible by the user who has a valid JWT token.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/middleware/)

```
def restrict_access_middleware(get_response):
    def middleware(request):
        # capture request path prefixed with 'private_contents' 
        if request.get_full_path().startswith('/private_contents/'):
            JWT_TOKEN = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')
            validate(JWT_TOKEN)
            # if fails then redirect
            return redirect('/disallowed/')
        else:
            return get_response(request)
    return middleware
```

Then you can register your `middleware` in your settings file